# Exchange Facebook SDK acces token for Azure B2C acces token

Tags: android, facebook, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm currently working on a mobile app and I want to use Facebook SDK access token on android to authenticate against a .NET Web Api.The Web Api is secured with Azure B2C Identity Management.
My Azure B2C Identity Management system uses Facebook as Identity provider.

What I want to achieve is to acquire an access token silently from the Azure B2C Identity Management System based on the Facebook SDK access token. The reason I want to achieve this is that if the user has already installed Facebook app on his mobile to not be forced to reenter his credentials.

I found this post which does something similar but using mobile services on azure https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2014/01/07/using-the-facebook-android-sdk-for-logging-in-to-azure-mobile-services/

What I want to achieve is something similar but using Azure B2C Signin Policy.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this isn't supported. You would instead have to use an OpenID Connect SDK like [AppAuth](https://appauth.io/) instead.

AppAuth uses features like [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) which shares cookies with the main browser so users don't have to re-login to sites like facebook.

Also, there is an [official tutorial for using AppAuth with Android using Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-android).